# Flow-based programming for windows?

Tags: automation

[image: Automate on Android]

I have been using Automate for Android (picture above) for a while and wonder if Windows has similar software.
I find flowcharts to be really helpful in organising each action for automation.

Currently I use a combination of CMD, Powershell, Autohotkey, AutoIt scripts but would like to know if there is one like Automate.

Comment: What about using Node-RED on Windows?

Comment: can Node-Red run powershell script/python scripts?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment. Give Node-RED a try.

https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/windows

https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-powershell
https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-pythonshell

See exec  Node. 
And so on.